# What's the difference between Lookup and conditional split in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

In my case, I have to look if my product already exists in a table before insert or update datas, what is the difference between using conditional split or a lookup ?
[image]
I think the lookup is the best solution because it's just true/false condition (I check the product code to verify if the product is in the table) but my colleague told me the Conditional split is better but not why.
Do Conditional split have better performance?

Comment: It is difficult to say. I guess you would have to test it yourself. It depends if it is worth testing - if you have billions of rows then might worth a shot otherwise I would stick with simplest possible method.

Comment: Potentially, I have 10 000 rows to insert or update so I can't really see the difference. I'll try to improve with 100 000 rows. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how you can even substitute one for the other.   The lookup gets information from an outside source, while the conditional split does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Conditional Split is useful for working on a dataset and the Lookup is for a simple condition.

For example, imagine I need to work on products from 2016 and another works on products of 2017. In this case I will add a Conditional Split to the Source with conditions `Year=2016` and and other line with `year=2017` to get 2 flux (2 arrows) containing 2 datasets. The first with 2016 products and the second with 2017 products. In my case, I don't modify the source dataset so I have to use Lookup because it's just a condition.